# Confused between -libjars and -archives to distribute side data to task nodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce job which uses a 3rd party jar and for passing a jar file to the task nodes I know that there are 2 ways to do it which is `hadoop jar -archive /custom.jar` or `hadoop jar -libjars /custom.jar` provided my Job uses GenericOptionsParser.

My Question is which is the best option to choose, as jar files can be passes by both -archive and -libjars options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-libjar is mostly suited to ship jars as documentation says. -archive is a general purpose and the option unarchives them(this might not be needed for jar usage, as you will never want the jar to be unzipped) at the task node. archive is mostly for shipping any other files and making them available at the task node.